# Can't reinstall Ubuntu - goes straight to grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I just recently installed Ubuntu in a dual boot setup with Windows. I decided I didn't want to have Windows on there anymore, and I want to make some changes to the ubuntu install, so I tried to reinstall using the usb flash drive. Every time I try to boot from the usb drive (I tell my bios to load from that drive) it goes straight to the grub loader asking me to choose which OS I want to use and won't let me go into the installation program. How do I make my computer boot into installation program on the usb drive?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Making your usb-thumb-drive boot first is controlled by your hardware (and BIOS settings), not Ubuntu thus we possibly can't help you.  I'll note some [of my] hardware won't boot a usb-thumb-drive if more than one drive is installed (ie. it boots usb-device and cannot select which) so you could check for this (other of my hardware asks). This question could be off-topic because it's not Ubuntu specific, but a question of how to boot for your hardware (I can press <F9> for some of mine, others I press the black-unlabelled key, some blue key.. ie. machine specific)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only problem there is that I was able to boot to the usb once, that's how I originally installed ubuntu. It's only now... after installing ubuntu -  that I cannot load from the usb stick. I'm following the same steps as before to boot from the usb, and it seems to start to do that, but then the grub loader comes up and takes over.

Comment: I would test the usb-thumb-drive on another machine? ie. does it boot elsewhere; just using the 'try ubuntu' or 'live' mode.  I would also use the other machine to 'test media' to ensure it's correct if it boots.  After you downloaded, did you verify the download? (ie. checksum validation), and then verify the write-to-media? (why it has the check media function)  These steps rarely show anything, but if skipped you're looking at days-weeks of diagnosing that the 30 seconds for this can check can skip.  Also check it's the only usb-storage-media inserted (some machines can only handle one)

Comment: I used the same thumb drive to install ubuntu the first time, roughly 8 hours before attempting this time. It was fully functional and had no issues. I may try just installing a different version of ubuntu to see if that gets picked up.